# Generally determine if the series is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^n)};x>1 $$

Just need a tip on which strategy to use to determine if this series converges or not.

Comment: try to get an idea of which order the n-th term is. Then compare with simpler series.

Comment: Would the ratio test work for this question?

Comment: The ratio test does work actually. Try it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The denominator is greater than $x^{1+2+\cdots+n}$, which is $x^{(n)(n+1)/2}$.

Thus the $n$-th term is $\lt \frac{1}{x^{n(n-1)/2}}$.  Thus the $n$-th term  is rapidly decaying. In particular, for $n\ge 3$, it is $\lt \frac{1}{x^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving out first $2$ terms doesn't affect the convergence, so
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^n)}\le\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{x\cdot x^{n-1}\cdot x^n}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \left(\frac1x\right)^n$$
Which is a geometric series and converges because $\dfrac1x<1$.